# How do I access the host from the guest in vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I have a Ubuntu 14.10 64-bit box running in vagrant on a Windows 8.1 64-bit host.

In this [book](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/vagrant-up-and/9781449336103/ch04.html) it is said that if I set a `host-only` network, I should be able to access the host with the same ip address as the guest if I change the last octet to `1`:

```
config.vm.network "hostonly", "192.168.33.10"
```

In the latest vagrant, `hostonly` is not available any more, so I tried setting it to `private_network`.

However, I am not able to ping `192.138.33.1` from my guest.

How do I access the host from the guest when using vagrant?

Answer (score 0):

Ping doesn't work. You can connect your host server by this way

```
ssh user@192.138.33.1
```

If your host server has ssh service enabled.